# How to install clouldflare workers site cli wrangler

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am trying to install wrangler using this command
npm i @cloudflare/wrangler@1.10.3
and when i am using this command i am getting this response [image]

and when i went to the /home/amarjeet/node_modules/@cloudflare/wrangler this path i see these files [image]

but when i use wrangler generate --site static
in the first image folder that is staticPages it gives this error

```
zsh: command not found: wrangler
```

i don't know how to solve this error i am unable to install wrangler.

Answer (score 3):

Since you used `npm i` without `-g`, wrangler is installed locally to the project, not globally on your system. In this case, you can run it with `npx wrangler`. `npx` is a tool that comes with `npm` and is used to run programs that are installed locally within a project.

Comment: can you suggest me one more thing after generating the worker site i got 2 folders and 1 file 2 folders are public and worker-site and one file is cred file so i wanted to ask one thing from where should i publish or preview the code 

static is the main folder and i ran npx generate site practice
then i got a folder name practice and inside the practice there is 2 folders and one file so i have to publish inside the practice folder?

Comment: Hi @mikkelReng, sorry I'm not sure I understand your question. It sounds like you had a site project, and then you generated a whole new project called `practice` inside it, so now you have two projects. The `generate` command is used to start a new project; you shouldn't run it inside an existing project. Anyway, you can find documentation on how to use workers sites here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/sites